# MS Access is displaying multoiple instances of a record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

In my MS-Access database, all the data are entered . The table for the report has 20 records in it of which all of them must be printed in a separate page. While viewing at the Print preview, each record is being displayed 20 times. i.e 1,2,3,......20 then again 1,2,3,....20.
I just need to print them only one.
Any suggestions???

Comment: What exactly is the report's data source? It sounds like that data source has an erroneous CROSS JOIN.

Comment: @mjh the data source is only one table and cheers !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! it worked!!!!!